# Android animate appearance listview item

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-animation

How can i scale the last and first listview item (depend of finger position)?

For example, ListView, contains 10 elements. Visible only 5. We start scrolling, new element from bottom started scaling from minimal scale, old first visible element started scale down. If we stopped scroll (but not touch up) scale saved.

This is not animation in the usual sense. How can i to make it?